# show error when compile lib that I wrapped for basic4android

Tags: github, word-wrap, basic4android

I wrapped a source github for b4a with Eclipse.

I added core.jar but when I compile the project in b4a it shows this error:

> trouble processing "java/com/lsjwzh/widget/materialloadingprogressbar/CircleProgressBar$OvalShadow.class": Ill-advised or mistaken usage of a core class (java.* or javax.*) when not building a core library.
>
> This is often due to inadvertently including a core library file in your application's project, when using an IDE (such as Eclipse). If you are sure you're not intentionally defining a core class, then this is the most likely explanation of what's going on.
>
> However, you might actually be trying to define a class in a core namespace, the source of which you may have taken, for example, from a non-Android virtual machine project. This will most assuredly not work. At a minimum, it jeopradizes the compatibility of your app with future versions of the platform.

[image: show image error]

I changed package name from

```
java.com.lsjwzh.widget.materialloadingprogressbar
```

to

```
com.lsjwzh.widget.materialloadingprogressbar
```

Why show in error -

> "java/com/lsjwzh/widget/materialloadingprogressbar/CircleProgressBar$OvalShadow.class"

?

I rebuilt the project in eclipse and compile with SimpleLibraryCompiler for b4a.

[image: and this is my project and OvalShadow Class]

Comment: You should give the error in the post, and give some more detail as to what you are doing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I forgot use

> @DependsOn

for calling Additional jar in folder libs.